# Prime generator from one to n

Tags: c++, primes

My code calculates primes from one to n. I have verified that the code always produces all the primes in that range correctly.

Are there any optimizations that I can make? Are there any bad programming practices besides variable names (e.g. l is close to 1)? Any better normal Windows API? I am using the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

#define printprimes() //for each(bool b in primes) cout << b << endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const double s = GetTickCount();
    unsigned long long numt;
    if(argc < 2) {
        cout << "Usage: "<<argv[0]<<" <primes until...>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    else if(atoi(argv[1])<1) {
        cout << "Usage: "<<argv[0]<<" <primes until...>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    numt = atol(argv[1])+1;

    bool skipprint = false;

    if(argc >=3) if(!strcmp(argv[2], "noprint")) skipprint = true;

    vector<bool> primes(numt);

    primes.assign(numt, true);

    primes[0] = false;
    primes[1] = false;

    long double sqrtt = sqrt(numt);
    for(unsigned long long l = 0; l<=sqrtt; l++) {
        if(!primes[l]) {
            //cout << l << " is false" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        for(unsigned long long cl = 2*l; cl < numt; cl+= l) {
            //cout << cl << ", a multiple of " << l << endl;
            primes[cl] = false;
        }
    }
    const double m = GetTickCount();
    unsigned long long count = 0;
    if(!skipprint) for(unsigned long long l = 0; l<numt; l++) if(primes[l]) {
        cout << l << endl;
        count ++;
    }
    if(skipprint) for(unsigned long long l = 0; l<numt; l++) if(primes[l]) count ++;
    const double e = GetTickCount();
    cout << endl;
    cout << count << " primes less than or equal to " << numt-1 << endl;
    cout << "Calculation took " << m-s << " ms";
    if(!skipprint) cout << " and printing took " << e-m << " ms";
    else cout << " and counting took " << e-m << " ms";
    cout <<"." << endl;
    //for each(bool b in primes) cout << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm looks good overall. Here are a few comments :

---

`using namespace std;` is [sometimes frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) : some might say that putting it in a cpp file (by opposition to a header file) is ok, some might say that it's not. In any case, it is worth having a read at the link.

---

```
#define printprimes() //for each(bool b in primes) cout << b << endl;
```

does not seem really useful.

---

If you want to handle wrong input in a better way you could have a look at the [other ways to convert arrays of char to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093414/convert-char-array-to-single-int).

---

```
bool skipprint = false;

if(argc >=3) if(!strcmp(argv[2], "noprint")) skipprint = true;
```

can become :

```
bool skipprint = false;
if(argc >=3 && !strcmp(argv[2], "noprint")) skipprint = true;
```

which is nothing but :

```
bool skipprint = (argc >=3 && !strcmp(argv[2], "noprint"));
```

Also it might be even better to do :

```
bool print = (argc < 3 || strcmp(argv[2], "noprint"));
```

---

```
    if(!primes[l]) {
        //cout << l << " is false" << endl;
        continue;
    }
    for(unsigned long long cl = 2*l; cl < numt; cl+= l) {
        //cout << cl << ", a multiple of " << l << endl;
        primes[cl] = false;
    }
```

can be written :

```
    if(primes[l]) {
        for(unsigned long long cl = 2*l; cl < numt; cl+= l) {
            //cout << cl << ", a multiple of " << l << endl;
            primes[cl] = false;
        }
    }
```

---

In `for(unsigned long long l = 0; l<=sqrtt; l++)`, you can start from index 2. Please note that if you forget to initialise prime[0] to false, you'll get stuck in an infinite loop.

---

In `for(unsigned long long cl = 2*l; cl < numt; cl+= l)`, you can start at index `l*l` because any `i*l` with `i < l` should have been crossed out already.

---

```
if(!skipprint) for(unsigned long long l = 0; l<numt; l++) if(primes[l]) {
    cout << l << endl;
    count ++;
}
if(skipprint) for(unsigned long long l = 0; l<numt; l++) if(primes[l]) count ++;
```

could be rewritten in many different ways. Most obvious one is to use an `else` :

```
if (skipprint) for(unsigned long long l = 0; l<numt; l++) if(primes[l]) count ++;
else for(unsigned long long l = 0; l<numt; l++) if(primes[l]) {
    cout << l << endl;
    count ++;
}
```

A probably better option in order not to repeat code is to do :

```
for(unsigned long long l = 0; l<numt; l++) if(primes[l]) {
    if (!skipprint)
        cout << l << endl;
    count ++;
}
```

---

Also, you should probably write your algorithm in a function on its own. Other optimisation can be analysed like removing all even numbers from the beginning to use a smaller container.

Comment: the printprimes was debug which was commented out so I didn't have to remove all the instances. They have all been removed now. The double ifs are there because for some reason the program evaluates both before deciding. primes[0] is always init to false because it represents 0 which is not a prime number. `i` will always be greater than l. I will take everything you told me in to account, though.

Comment: `is sometime frowned upon`! Any body doing this in real production code should be shot. FIne if you do it in a ten line program that you write to test something. But anything that goes public should not have it in. Your just shooting the maintainer in the foot.

Comment: Yeah @LokiAstari I am not planning on writing an big program for a while yet. If I do, It will be in Java.

Answer (score 1):

> Any better normal Windows API?

The `GetTickCount` function returns a `DWORD` not a `double`.

According to the documentation it wraps every 50 days, so there's a `GetTickCount64` function to avoid this problem.

Its resolution is in the 10..60 msec range, which isn't great for measuring the performance of fast code; there's a `QueryPerformanceCounter` function used with `QueryPerformanceFrequency` which you can use for measuring shorter intervals.

---

Also, this looks strange to me ...

```
vector<bool> primes(numt);
```

Does `vector` support an `unsigned long long` size? Maybe you should be using `size_t` everywhere instead of `unsigned long long`.

Comment: vector does support unsigned long long. at least on visual studio.

Comment: ULONGLONG means 64-bit on a Windows 32-bit machine. When you say that "`vector` does support `unsigned long long`" is that on 32-bit or 64-bit windows? Have you tried it with a number bigger than 2<sup>32</sup>? Don't you agree that `size_t` (or `vector::size_type`) is the only type that `vector` really supports as a constructor parameter?

Comment: 64 bit windows... 2^32 is larger than the amount of ram than my system has. I have exactly 4GB of memory.